# codeless automation tools are you using for Salesforce testing

Tags: automation, uipath, tosca

We are currently doing manual testing. .we are looking for codeless automation tools for Salesforce testing end to end .which one is really good in the market

Only manual testing of application is performed

Can RPA tools be also considered ?